# Android- Opening a browser when user clicks a notification

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, notifications, android-pendingintent

Hi I wanted to create a notification that will open a browser when user clicks on it. But the notification simply disappears and that's it. I have already made houndreds of versions of this code:

```
    private void sendNotification(String url){

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(MediaMonitorService.this,0,intent,0);
    long[] vibrations = {250,250,500,250,250};
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MediaMonitorService.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("MediaMonitor notification")
                    .setContentText(notificationMessage)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(vibrations)
                    .setLights(0xff00ff00,300,1000)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(hashString(url), mBuilder.build());
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is this value in hashString(url) ?

Comment: I don't see any issue with code ,it works for me , but check the value in hashString(url) .

Comment: The value of hashString(url) is valid and the notifications shows up. The problem is that when I click it nothing happens- the browser doesn't show up.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that url didn't have "http://" at the beginning.